# how will read csv file into dataset?

Tags: c#

i want to read csv file using c#.

Comment: Google "c# csv dataset"? The first 8-10 results all look promising (and easy).

Comment: It is very generic question make sure you try from your end before posting in SO

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has standard driver for text file MS-Text driver. You can use and load effortlessly.

```
string strConn = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" +
  "Dbq=C:;Extensions=csv,txt";

try
{
  OdbcConnection objCSV = new OdbcConnection(strConn);
  objCSV.Open();

  OdbcCommand oCmd = new OdbcCommand("select column1,column2 " +
    "from THECSVFILE.CSV", objCSV);
  OdbcDataReader oDR = oCmd.ExecuteReader();

  while (oDR.read())
  {
    // Do something
  }
  oDR.Close();
  oCmd.Dispose();
  objCSV.Close();
}
catch {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try out 
[A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)

It's a CodeProject project and should fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, this is also very good. If you have a large data file, this is a good option. I used it earlier. @Morten Thanks for it. I somehow forgot it. Definitely +1